# Delete all rows but the latest date

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I've got this table `supp_props`:

```
supp_id | supp_dry_weight | supp_price | supp_date
--------+-----------------+------------+------------ 
  22    |      88.00      |   27.50    | 2015-06-25   x delete
  22    |      89.00      |   28.00    | 2015-10-18       < don't delete, while
  22    |      89.00      |   29.50    | 2015-12-20         this row here is in the future
  23    |      84.00      |   15.00    | 2015-06-23   x delete
  23    |      42.50      |   7.50     | 2015-06-25   x delete
  23    |      35.60      |   5.00     | 2015-06-29
  24    |      89.00      |   18.20    | 2015-06-25
  25    |      89.15      |   18.50    | 2015-08-05
  26    |      89.00      |   28.30    | 2015-06-25
```

And I want to delete all rows that are 'old', but there are some conditions:

- a row must be older than two weeks to be deleted.
- if there is no row with a more current date it shouldn't be deleted.
- There may be rows that are in the future, if so, this row shouldn't be seen as a 'more current' date (for the above rule).

How can I achieve that with mysql?

Comment: Well, this might have been much easier if there was one column PK in your table!

Comment: Have you made any attempts to implement something? What problems are you running into?

Comment: why `2015-10-18` *is in the future* it is in the past. Calrify the date of *today*

Comment: @Alex, `2015-10-18` should not be deleted, will the row under it `2015-12-20` lies in the future. Today is the date of today `2015-11-12`

Comment: you're not going to be able to do this with a single query. you'll need at least ONE subquery to do the "any rows in future" inventory.

Comment: @MikeBrant, since I'm no sql expert, I get stuck right here... with having no idea where to start with my query. Believe me, I've been bumping my head for days, before I asked the question.

Comment: @LinkinTED check my answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all the great help and examples from Alex, Mike Brent and xQbert I've managed to create this query:

```
DELETE sp 
FROM supp_props sp
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT supp_id, MAX( supp_date ) AS max_date
   FROM supp_props
   WHERE supp_date < NOW()
   GROUP BY supp_id
) max
ON sp.supp_id = max.supp_id
WHERE sp.supp_date < ( DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 week ) )
AND sp.supp_date <> max.max_date
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
DELETE sp FROM supp_props AS sp
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT supp_id, MAX(supp_date) AS max_date
    FROM supp_props
    WHERE supp_date <= DATE(NOW())
) AS max
    ON sp.supp_id = max.supp_id
    AND sp.supp_date = max.max_date
WHERE max.supp_id IS NULL
AND sp.supp_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

What you are doing here is making a join against a subselect (aliased as `max`) that contains the highest date for each `supp_id` (while excluding rows where where the `supp_date` is in the future).  By making a LEFT JOIN against that `max` subselect, you would "protect" all rows having the maximum date for the given `supp_id` by only deleting cases where the join result ends up having a `NULL` value for fields in `max`.  This is achieved by the first part of the WHERE clause.

You then apply the condition that the record must also be older than two weeks as the second part of the WHERE clause.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for your answer. I've tested it live. If an supp_id has all dates in the past, it deletes all posts. I've changed the `DELETE` to `SELECT` to see what it gives. The `supp_id` and `max_date` from the left join are always NULL... Any thoughts? Also a little typo, `DATESUB` should be `DATE_SUB` :)

Answer (score 0):

First you will need a PK for your table. I assume you would use the id as a PK.

You will have to use [NOW()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp)

DELETE FROM supp_props 
WHERE supp_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK;

If your table stores datetimes in different timezone than what NOW() returns, you can use UTC_TIMESTAMP() instead to get the timestamp in UTC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't cover the question... please look at the conditions...

Comment: @LinkinTed What have you tried yourself sofar? You will probably need a subquery as MarcB said

Answer (score 0):

You should have a PK column for the table to easily do this..

Without PK you can only use a select sub query that select all data that is in the past but not future, and sort by date, then group by your supp_id to be a tmp table

Then execute the query to delete all data from your table that with condition supp_id and supp_date are not exists in the tmp table.

But this are not a good way to delete data .. still PK as suggest..

Comment: Is this really an answer or a comment?  While having a single column (i.e. autoincrement) PK would make the join easier, it is certainly not something that would be required to do what the OP wants done.

Comment: just check yourself to other answer and see if the logic correct for their query? This will be an answer if you willing to figure out how to build your query with the logic and it might be only comment if you never want to try it yourself. yes PK would make the join easier but also PK is better for deleting as we only need compare one column instead of two or three.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16d9d/1

```
DELETE t1 FROM `t1` t1
LEFT JOIN `t1` t
ON t1.supp_id = t.supp_id
    AND t1.supp_date < t.supp_date 
    AND t.supp_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 WEEK)
WHERE t1.supp_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 WEEK)
    AND t.supp_id IS NOT NULL;
```